# How to show already prepared charts based on cell value in excel?

Tags: excel, graph

For eg. If Cell address "A1" has a letter "apple", then cell "B1" should show charts which i have already prepared on "apple". If "A1" is "Orange", it will change to orange chart.

Any idea if it is possible?

Comment: yeh should be possible. What are you expecting from us

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with VBA, like below, simply put the code under the Sheet you are using and amend the Sheet1 to whatever sheet name you have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'if data changes on Cell A1
        Value = Target.Value 'get the value from A1
        If Value = "Apple" Then 'if value is "Apple" then
            ws.ChartObjects("chtApple").Visible = True 'Show chtApple, the name of the Chart
            ws.ChartObjects("chtOrange").Visible = False 'Hide chtOrange
        ElseIf Value = "Orange" Then
            ws.ChartObjects("chtApple").Visible = False
            ws.ChartObjects("chtOrange").Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. You have given me the reason to work on VBA. Grateful to you for personalized answer. :)

Comment: @AumIsha please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)